# Flash player version greater than 10.2.161.23?

Tags: internet-explorer, flash

I want to carry out some testing to check if my application works fine with Flash player versions greater than 10.2.161.23 (for IE).

Can anyone kindly let me know the versions greater than 10.2.161.23? (I should also be able to download the Flash player.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Flash Player 10.3 and Flash Player 11 are available from [Adobe Labs](http://labs.adobe.com/)

Comment: Are they 64-bit flash players or 32-bit? Can you give some info on this.

Comment: A few different features are being developed in parallel.  The 64-bit Flash Player is a branch called "Square" (Currently at 10.2.161.23).  Hardware accelerated 3D is a branch called "Incubator" (Flash Player 11.0.0.58).  There's also the beta of the next release (Flash Player 10.3.180.65).

Answer (score 0):

I could find flash player 10.3 beta in adobe labs site, but couldn't find Flash Player 11 there though.